# Remove background noise from audio file in Matlab and simulink

Tags: matlab, audio, simulink

I've an assignment that requires combining audio signal with a noise signal and getting the original audio signal undistorted using digital filters.

the problem is that I can't get the original audio back because I can't estimate the noise content in frequency domain. I used as a trial of a Butterworth Lowpass filter with 10th order and tried to guess the cutoff frequency but always the resultant file still noisy.

Any Help ?

here is my steps below:

```
%% Load the original audio file to matlab Workspace
test_audio ='J:\test_read.wav'; 

 %% Load the noise audio file to Matlab workspace

noise ='J:\crowd_noise.wav';
%% read the original audio file for a finite length of time

[y,Fs] = audioread(test_audio,[1 262144]);


%%read the noise audio file for a finite length of time

[x,fs]=audioread(noise,[1 262144]); 

[p,q]=rat(Fs/fs);

 %% resample the noise file with the original file's sampling rate

m=resample(x,p,q);

m=m(:,1); %% take only one channel

Y=y(1:length(m),1); %% make the 2 streams of equal lengths

u=m+Y; %% the resultant noisy signal

%% DFT of the resultant signal

N=length(u);

df = Fs / N;


w = (-(N/2):(N/2)-1).*df;

U= fft(u,N) / N; %For normalizing, but not needed for our analysis


U = fftshift(U);

figure;

plot(w,abs(U);

spectrogram(u,256,[],[],Fs);colorbar


%% DFT of the original signal

df = Fs / N;

 w = (-(N/2):(N/2)-1).*df;


k= fft(y,N) / N; %For normalizing, but not needed for our analysis

K= fftshift(k);

figure;

plot(w,abs(K);

spectrogram(y,256,[],[],Fs);colorbar


[psdy,Fyy] = periodogram(y,rectwin(length(y)),length(y),Fs);

plot(Fyy,10*log10(psdy));

grid on;
```

---

The link below contains the FFT diagrams and the audio files:

http://1drv.ms/1FVtpC7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's surprising that the low-pass filter had no effect. Compare the FFT before and after the filter to make sure the filter is working as designed. Then set the filter corner frequency as low as possible without distorting the signal.

Comment: The LPF didn't work and generally different kinds of FIR and IIR filters with constant coefficients will not work. Also, it is difficult to remove the noise from the audio because the freq. spectra of the 2 signals are deeply overlapped and it is difficult to estimate the the exact range of the spectrum of the noise. Note that I added the noise .Wav file to the desired .Wav file to produce a noisy audio signal. I will try the adaptive digital filter to solve the problem.

Comment: I managed to filter the audio successfully using LMS adaptive filter. I changed the step size of the LMS algorithm for different values to get different qualities of output sound but with greater convergence for small step size values. The step size sometimes referred to as convergence parameter.